# How to create undefined count of loops

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to create a program, which would loop trough all letters.

I want for example show *aaaa*, then *aaab* to *aaaz*, then *aaba* and so on to *zzzz*.

The problem is: how to allow user to enter the letter count?

Here's my code with only 3 letters:

```
Dim abc() As String = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", _
    "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"}
Console.ReadLine()
Dim indx As Integer = 0
For a = 0 To 25
    For b = 0 To 25
         For c = 0 To 25
              Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}{2}", abc(a), abc(b), abc(c))           
         Next
    Next
Next
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recursion is the tool you're looking for here.  You want to repeat to a certain depth; that depth is the input from the user.  In this example I've provided a depth of 3 (meaning all permutations with three letters, as you described in your question).  You can change the value to whatever you wish, or better yet read input from the user.

```
Dim abc() As String = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"}

Sub Main()
    Dim depth As Integer
    depth = 3
    IterateAlphabet("", depth)
    Console.ReadKey()

End Sub

Sub IterateAlphabet(ByVal currentLetters As String, ByVal currentDepth As Integer)
    For letter = 0 To 25
        Dim newLetters As String
        newLetters = currentLetters + abc(letter)
        If (currentDepth = 1) Then
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", newLetters)
        Else
            IterateAlphabet(newLetters, currentDepth - 1)
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest recursion, I'm not confident in my VB skills, but here is a solution in C#

```
static String[] letters = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m",
                                "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z" };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Writeline("Enter the amount of characters");
        int count = Int32.Parse( Console.ReadLine() );
        outputStrings("", count);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static public void outputStrings(String startString, int letterCount)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < letters.Length; i++)
        {
            String temp = startString;
            temp += letters[i];

            if (temp.Length == letterCount)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(temp);
            }
            else
            {
                outputStrings(temp, letterCount);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could look at using an Inputbox. Allowing the user to choose the length.
[MSDN InputBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3yfdhzk5%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
Dim Length as Object
Message = "Hello"
Title = "Hello"
InputBox(Message, Title, Length)

Console.WriteLine(abc(Length))
```

This is off the top of my head but I believe with some tweaking it should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I am not firm on VB. This is a python code snippet that does the trick. Maybe you can take it as pseudo code and translate it to VB.

Anybody who can change this to VB, please edit my post.

strlen is the length of the output strings. a ** b is a to the power of b. a % b is a modulo b.

```
strlen = 5

for i in range (26 ** strlen):
    output = ''
    for j in range (strlen):
        output = chr ( (i / (26 ** j) ) % 26 + 97) + output
    print output
```

And don't overdo it with the output length. A length of 10 for instance wield yield 141167095653376 strings.